# ManagedBean, JSF 2, SessionScoped, RequestScoped

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, scope

i want to use in one mangedBean two type of scop : RequestScoped and SessionScoped

I have a list, I want to use it with sessionScoped
and others objects i want to use them with RequestScoped

can you help me please ?

Comment: Let me be wrong but this could't work. 1. Request Scope is handled by stateles beans and 2. session scope by stateful beans ;) What you can do is using two beans. One Stateful bean for your list and a stateles bean for the other object. Then you can inject the stateles bean into your stateful bean and have access. To give you a better example, pls provide some code.

Comment: thank you for your response, I try what you say

Comment: @rmertins that would work on ye olde JSF 1.x. Since JSF 2, you don't need to store lot of stuff in session, you have `@ViewScoped` to store the necessary elements of a `List<YourClass>` and perform ajax operations on the same list, without storing it in session (manually). Also, bean injection is not something I would recommend to do unless necessary (which in these days I find really not an option).

Comment: yes thats right but its not the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you first need to understand how Managed Beans and Managed Properties works in JSF.
You can make, for example, three Managed Beans, two Request Scoped (R1 and R2) and one Session Scoped (S1), and access Managed Beans Instances S1 and R1 from R2 using Managed Properties. Read about Managed Beans and Managed properties, JSF 1 only supports xml configuration, JSF 2 supports xml and annotation configurations for declaring Managed Beans and Managed Properties.

Comment: Ok Man thunk you ^^ for your response